# Jackpot Website Blank Space

Tags: php, html, css

I have 2 files with .php which I sycned with my database. I was trying to add a background to my Jackpot "RESULT" page. But I had a problem about the blank (white) space at the bottom.

here is my code of result.php :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RESULT</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            text-align: center;
            background-image:url(../images/background/background5.jpg);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:50% 50%;
            color: white;
        }
        #true {color:green; font-style:underline}
        #close {color:blue;}
        #false {color:red;}
        a {font-size:35; color: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) 
{
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
    die('Can\'t use '.DB_NAME.': '.mysql_error());
}
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config") or die(mysql_error());  
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number1']);
$b = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number2']);
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number3']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$d = "$a$b$c";
echo 'Guessed code:'.$d.'<br>';
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
    if($info['jackpot_code'] == $d)
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE `config` SET `jackpot_code`= ".rand(000,999)." WHERE `id`=1");
        echo '<a href="././jackpot.php"><img src="../images/img/jackpot1.gif" height="100px" width="200"/><br><div id="true">CORRECT!</div></a>';
    }   
    else if( $d + 30 > $info['jackpot_code'] && $info['jackpot_code'] > $d - 30){
        echo '<a href="././jackpot.php">Try again!</a><br>';
        die('<div id="close">The code u guessed is at the range of +/- 30 to jackpot.</div>');
    } else
    {
        echo '<a href="././jackpot.php">Try again!</a><br>';
        die('<div id="false">CODE FALSE!</div>');
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO jackpot_log (username, code, time) VALUES ('".$username."','".$d."','".$date->getTimestamp()."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) 
{
    die('Error: '. mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
</body>
```

And the picture of the page result.php: [RESULT PAGE IMAGE](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/752x564q90/560/1eh5.jpg)

IN CASE YOU NEED: jackpotpage.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RESULT</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
text-align: center;
background-image:url(../images/background/background5.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:50% 50%;
color: white;
}
img {
margin-top:25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="result.php" method="POST"/>
<img src="../images/img/jackpot2.jpg" height="150px" width="300"/><br></br>
<h1>Name:</h1>
<input type="text"     name="user_name">
<br><br>
<table cellpadding="5px"cellspacing="5px">
    <tr>
        <select name="number1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <select name="number2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <select name="number3">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
</table><br>
<input type="submit" value="TRY!">
</form>
</body>
```

[BACKGROUND IMAGE](http://imageshack.com/a/img716/1961/cm3v.jpg)

[JACKPOT PAGE IMAGE](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/572x429q90/827/bg51.jpg)

Comment: There are better tools to take a screenshot than actually using a camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
html { 
background: url(cm3v.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; //replace cm3v.jpg with your image path
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in:

Safari 3+
Chrome Whatever+
IE 9+
Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

source: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

In your result.php try to change this:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

to:

```
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

Comment: What do you mean by somehow dimmed? Also, can you send a link to the page. It will be a easier to debug with browser inspect tools.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img59/2227/yz7x.png I cant send a link to the page I'm working on XAMPP. Thats a localhost document.